# xml conversion to Object c#

Tags: c#, xml

If i have an xml of the form

```
<Details>
<Detail>
<Name1>Value1</Name1>
<Name2>Value2</Name2>
</Detail>
...
</Details>
```

And i define a class in my c# code for Detail and provide setters/getters for Name1, Name2 etc
is there an api to directly read the xml and create Detail objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) - this creates / parses xml from the shape of your object (so your property names need to match the attribute / element names in the xml).

If you need more control, you'll want to work with the newer [Linq to XML API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

[XSD.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) *can* produce a class file for you based on an XSD or XML file, but if you aim it an an XML file, you'll need a pretty representative one (with multiple elements wherever there can be multiple elements), otherwise you'll need to tweak a few things. It's a good start though...

Comment: This is exactly how I end up doing XML -> C#, especially if you've already defined a class for it.

Answer (score 2):

Linq to XML is pretty nice for this.

```
var details = from detail in document.Descendants("Detail")
              select new Detail { Name1 = detail.Element("Name1").Value, Name2 = detail.Element("Name2").Value };
```

(This assumes you have defined a type called Detail, you could very well omit the `Detail` and obtain an anonymous type.)

This code will result in an `IEnumarable<Detail>` (or anon. type) that you can iterate over for your objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `DataContractSerializer`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to use `XSD.exe` to create a C# class from the XML file - see [this post](http://collecteddotnet.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/xsd-xsd-tool-xsdexe-to-generate-net-class-file/) for details.
2. Use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the class:

   ```
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Details));  
   using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))  
   {  
       XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);  
       var result = (Details)serializer.Deserialize(reader);  
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
DetailList dl;
XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DetailList>))

using (Stream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\path\to\file.xml", FileMode.Open))
      dl = (DetailList)xmls.Deserialize(fs);
```

Make sure you have populated your classes with the correct attributes. Use

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// ...

[Serializable]
public class Detail
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name2 { get; set; }

    // REQUIRED: a parameterless constructor for XmlSerializer (can be private)
    private Detail(){}

    public Detail(string name1, string name2)
    {
        Name1 = name1;
        Name2 = name2;
    }
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("Details")]
public class DetailList : List<Detail>
{

}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Deatil))`